# TFS not copying to _PublishedWebsites\MyWeb\bin

Tags: tfsbuild

I have an MVC solution building on TFS. The solution does build without error or warning, but the first referenced .dll (Antlr3.Runtime.dll) is not getting copied into the _PublishedWebsites\MySolution.MyWeb\bin folder.

The .dll appears in the droplocation MySolution_20120629.11, but is not being put in the bin directory of the publishedwebsites. If I take Antlr3.Runtime.dll out of the solution then this problem happens to the next dll that the website references (Castle.Core.dll). If I put  Antlr3.Runtime.dll beck into the solution then Castle.Core.dll appears back in the bin folder.

The most obvious things that connect these two dlls is that they are alphabetically the first dll to be referenced by the website.

I am lost on how to debug or where to look next.  Any hints on how to find the problem would be appreciated.

Notes:

- Using TFS2012 RC.
- I cannot see any problems reported in log files.
- Copy local is set to true.

Comment: Have you tried changing build logging verbosity to "diagnostic" and looking through the logs?

Comment: Yes, I set the logging to diagnostic but there are no errors reported and the dll is mentioned whilst it is compiled etc.

Comment: Is this a Web Site or Web Application? Are the DLL's in the references list?